# Регистрозависимый ли оператор LIKE в субд MySQL?

Tags: sql, like, mysql

Регистрозависимый ли оператор LIKE в субд MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIKE` все по барабану, он сравнивает строки в зависимости от `COLLATION` - так что все определяется правилами `COLLATION`, которые задаются или при создании БД/таблицы или непосредственно при вызове `LIKE`

Answer (score 1):

Регистрозависимыми могут быть данные. В зависимости от этого LIKE может возвращать разный результат.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql всегда сравнивает строки в без учета регистра. Если нужно сравнить с учетом регистра используйте binary.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Смотрите документацию.